# What icon size is used for iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I submitted an App to Testflight. I uploaded the 1024x1024 icon file, and the application itself contains several other icon file sizes. I receive no errors on submission or warnings about missing icon files.

When I view the App in TestFlight, the icon appears.

However, when I view the App in the iPhone app "Connect" (which is iTunesConnect), the icon is blank in the "Recent Activity" or "Favorites" list. If I select the App to go to its "details" page, the icon shows.

What icon size/resolution do I need to add to my project, and is there a particular place I need to add it?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is go the Application Setting -> General tab and add the AppIcon or in Images.xcast set the icon set and add the relavent icon sizes to the Images.xcast  as in the Attached image [image]

Further you can select different devices for the icon from the right side of the screen . just drag and drop the specific icons to there desire places

Comment: Dont need thumbs up just want that answer may help you

Answer (score 0):

[appicon.build](http://www.appicon.build/) is a very nice and simple site to convert your icons and launchImage in all different sizes available for iOS devices. I tried it several times.

*Disclaimer: I'm not associated with them in any way.*